# How to expand table view with increasing cell number in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have three section and each section have one cell. when i click on cell  of a section, cell number will increase. That means that section will reload only. how can i do this?

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, 1);
NSIndexSet *section = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range];                                     
[self.tableView reloadSections:section withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

how can i implement this method? 
reloadSections does not call.

Answer (score 0):

Insert necessary value or object in your source array and then try to reload the section.

You can also use:

```
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexpaths withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationNone]
```

1. Here `indexpaths` is the array of new index paths
2. In both cases you need to update your source array or dictionary (whatever you are using)